# Issue creating initial migration .NET Core & EntityFramework & PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Running into an issue when trying to set up my first migration. I am using EF 3.1.1, I have a layer for data which is SunshineCoffee.Data and another layer for Web which is SunshineCoffee.Web. The migrations will update a PostgreSQL database.

I run the following command:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../SunshineCoffee.Web migrations add InitialMigration
```

and receive the following error:

**Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:

- You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
- You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
- You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.**

Here is my CSPROJ file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SunshineCoffee.Data\SunshineCoffee.Data.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

[Snapshot of my Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp6oK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The dotnet ef tool is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK** that is why you are getting the above error. I have the same issue earlier and resolved by using the following:

To be able to manage migrations or scaffold a DbContext, install dotnet ef as a global tool typing the following command in terminal:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

For a specific version you can use the following command:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.1.4
```

For more information regarding this [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#the-ef-core-command-line-tool-dotnet-ef-is-no-longer-part-of-the-net-core-sdk)